# Sum of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

I am trying to obtain the distribution of $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i}$ when the distribution of each i.i.d. random variable $X_{i}$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_{X_{i}}(x) = \begin{cases}\lambda e^{\lambda x}, & 0 \le x \le R\\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $R = \ln 2 / \lambda$ so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_{i}}(x) = 1$.

You can easily notice that the random variable $X_{i}$ is distributed as *horizontally flipped* from the exponential distribution.

I am in the need to find what distribution $Y$ follows. Can anybody help?

Comment: 1) The integral of $f_X$ is not $1$ so it is the distribution function of nothing;
2) It seems that your $X_i$ are bounded by $R$ so $Y$ is bounded by $NR$, so it cannot follow a gamma distribution, which affects positive mass to any neighbourhood of $+\infty$

Comment: @Will I mean, yes, assuming that the integral of the PDF goes to a 1, by setting $R = \text{ln} 2 / \lambda$ in the given case.

Comment: Ok. But the argument against the gamma distribution still holds.

Comment: @Will Right. It was my conjecture. I just need to find what distribution the sum follows. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. We can easily find a closed form of the characteristic function. Find the CF of the rv $X_1$:
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\theta X_1}]&=\lambda\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{I}_{[0,R]}e^{\lambda x}e^{ix\theta}dx=\\
&=\lambda \int_{[0,R]}e^{x(\lambda +i\theta)}dx=\\
&=\lambda \frac{e^{R(\lambda + i\theta)}-1}{\lambda + i \theta}\end{aligned}$$
By IIDness:
$$E[e^{i\theta Y}]=E[e^{i\theta X_1}]^n=\lambda^n\bigg(\frac{e^{R\lambda}e^{i\theta R}-1}{\lambda+i\theta}\bigg)^n=\lambda^n\bigg(\frac{2e^{i\theta R}-1}{\lambda+i\theta}\bigg)^n$$
With numerical integration we can see the shape of the density of $Y_n$ and how it changes with $n$ (as expected, it becomes more and more bell shaped):

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing the approach. Could you elaborate how you found the density from $E[e^{i\theta Y}]$?

Comment: @MoKim if you mean the densities in the image, I applied an inverse Fourier transform numerically

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qDtqiX1I-3ciEhj1dSMSIdL6AbwsGVK1X-e_KGZhODE/edit?usp=sharing
Could you take a look at what I have done for the numerical inverse FT? Mine looks off what you showed. I think I made a mistake in setting the range of x.

Comment: @MoKim leave an upvote if the answer is useful

Comment: Just did. Thanks again for the useful advice! Kindly take a look at the code that I shared.

Comment: @MoKim you need better numbers. My pic resulted from a range of $\theta$ from $-3000$ to $3000$ with a step size of $\Delta\theta \approx 0.06$ and a range of $x$ from $-10$ to $10$ with a step size of $\Delta x \approx 0.03$

Answer (score 1):

If you set $Y_i = R-X_i$, you find that $Y_i$ has the [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) exponential distribution. There are some papers on sums of truncated exponential distributions, for example Nath (1974). Check also the CrossValidated post ["PDF of sum of truncated exponential distribution"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269170/pdf-of-sum-of-truncated-exponential-distribution).

*Nath, G. Baikunth*, [**On sums and products of truncated exponential variates**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03461238.1974.10408682), Scand. Actuarial J. 1974, 205-210 (1974). [ZBL0292.62015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0292.62015).

Comment: It isn't a truncated exponential; the exponent is positive in my $X_{i}$.

Comment: I never said $X_i$ is a truncated exponential. Apply the change of variable $Y_i = R-X_i$ to get the density function of $Y_i$, observe the minus sign in the exponent, and observe that $Y_i$ has the truncated exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$, truncated at $R=(\ln 2)/\lambda$.

Comment: Oh sorry now I see what you meant. Could you take a look at what I found? I still doubt that the $Y_{i}$ is a truncated exponential after seeing what I have got. Did I make any mistake?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqpLwLv7AypdHdbLUOBhxMq8XS_u72aW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Surely you have some mistake because you ended up with a density function $-e^{\lambda R} e^{-\lambda y}$, which is negative. I'll let you to find the mistake(s) yourself.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in setting the range of the integral in the equation of (a). Do you see how to fix it?

Comment: Hey Jukka, could you take a look at this? I think I got the mistake corrected. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxTMP5VKyHLqPaf7hFVYgpvY4tJUglaN/view?usp=sharing